# Flutter: child widgets (that are passed as constructor arguments) to parent, emitting events to parent widget?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

So i have a `ChipSet` widget that gets passed a list of `MyChip` widgets in the constructor.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:hello_world/widgets/chip.dart';

class ChipSet extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<MyChip> chips;

  ChipSet({
    Key key,
    @required this.chips,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChipSetState createState() => _ChipSetState();
}

class _ChipSetState extends State<ChipSet> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: widget.chips
    );
  }
}
```

The chip widget's code is the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class MyChip extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool active;
  final Color color;
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;
  final EdgeInsets padding;

  MyChip({
    Key key,
    @required this.color,
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.text,
    this.active = false,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(0)
  }) : super(key: key);

  void _onTap() {
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: _onTap,
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                color: active ? color : Colors.white),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon( icon, size: 15),
                Padding(
                  padding: padding,
                  child: Text(text,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.black)),
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

I want the following: For the `ChipSet` widget to have only one active `MyChip` at any given time. A click on the chip widget would make that `MyChip` active, and thereby make all other `MyChip` s in that `ChipSet` inactive.

The problem that i am having is that I do not know to access a method on my parent `ChipSet` widget from my chip widget when the `MyChip` is tapped on `_onTap` method, for example. 
Does anyone know an elegant solution to this type of state management problem? Also, i would like the child `MyChip` widget to pass along it's value, meaning when the `MyChip` is set to active and the others to inactive, the parent gets the value of the active `MyChip`. (for example `value` would be a property of `MyChip`)

My main problem is that this `ChipSet` gets passed these chips as constructor arguments.

I am aware of the pattern wherein the parent passes a callback of it's to the child (to the child widgets constructor.). But in this use-case I do not see how that pattern is applicable seeing as the widgets are passed into the `ChipSet`.

I would be very grateful for help on this. Best regards.

Comment: you can read a little bit about that : https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e

Comment: @diegoveloper Thank you. This is exactly what I need: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model

Comment: If you could share a sample solution using the [scoped_model](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model) that you've found [in the blog post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e), it would be a helpful reference for the community.